# When i`m trying to run this command 'sencha framework upgrade ext C:\Users\emushkov\bin\Sencha\Cmd\6.5.3.6' a series of errors occur in cmd

Tags: javascript, extjs, sdk, frameworks

`I was given the source files of a project written in Ext JS, and the Readme.md file indicates that I need to execute the following command: 'sencha framework upgrade ext d:\Sencha\SDK\ext-6.5.2'. I tried to do it, but I changed the path to where my Sencha CMD is located. As far as I understand, the framework is downloaded together with CMD, so now the command looks like this: 'sencha framework upgrade ext C:\Users\emushkov\bin\Sencha\Cmd\6.5.3.6.However, I received the following errors:[ERR] Directory C:\Users\emushkov\Desktop\Lising\src\Client\ext not recognized as a framework[INF] Upgrading framework ext[ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for 'modern'![ERR] The following versions cannot be satisfied:[ERR] elp: modern (No matches!)[ERR] Command must be run from a framework folderI don't understand the following:

1. Does the framework come bundled with Sencha CMD, or do I need to download it separately?
2. Why do I need to execute the command 'sencha framework upgrade ext d:\Sencha\SDK\ext-6.5.2' if I already have version 6.5.2 installed locally?First, I tried running this command not from the project directory, but from the framework directory, but I got the following error: 'Command must be run from a workspace folder.'
   Then I returned to the project directory and received this error: 'Framework ext does not exist, adding to workspace.json.

But it didn't help either and led to the errors I mentioned earlier.
I also found on one of the forums that I need to specify the framework path in the file /.sencha/workspace/sencha.cfg, but that didn't help either.`

[structure of projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiOJb.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frameworks do not come with Sencha CMD (there are many versions), you have to download them manually and save to a local folder. You can have many different versions.

Whenever a new project is created with Sencha CMD or with npm the framework of your choice will be copied into the `ext` folder under your project's root directory and files are generated for you project (`app.json`, `build.xml` etc.)

So if you have a project that has an older version of Ext JS embedded in it's `ext` folder, you need to run `upgrade`. This will both override files in the `ext` folder and make other adjustments needed for you project to be compatible with the upgrade version. Always do a full backup before upgrading.

Comment: You're very welcome for the answer! May I clarify two more points? 1) I tried to download Ext JS 6.5.3 SDK from the official website, but the link led me to download SenchaCmd-7.6.0. Does it mean that I can't download the framework itself without a license? 2) As far as I understand, the Ext JS framework should be present in the project itself, but it's not there. I will attach a screenshot of the project structure."
@Peter Koltai

Comment: Sure thing. Sencha has an [Ext JS Community Edition](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/communityedition/) if you meet the criteria. Otherwise it is licensed or trial version. It should be present but it is common not to check it into git because of the size.

Comment: As for the project it seems to be a package and not an app. But I am not sure from the screenshot you attached.

Comment: You're welcome!
And one final question, please.
In the project I was given, there is no 'ext' folder. As I understand it, this folder contains the files of the framework itself. Is it necessary to have such a folder in the project, or can this framework be a dependency in the package.json?
So, if I meet the criteria [ext js community edition](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/communityedition/), does it mean I will be able to download the specific version of the Ext JS framework I need? @ Peter Koltai

Comment: Yes, you will be able to download the community edition. You need these files to develop with Ext JS, this are JavaScript files which contain the framework code.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. I'm having trouble understanding how to download or install the Ext 6.5.2 package into my project with the source code. I registered for Ext Community Edition and executed the command 'npm i @sencha/ext-gen,' but what do I need to do to have the ext-6.5.2 framework version appear in my project?
@Peter Koltai

Comment: Normally it is copied when you create a new project. You can manually copy the `ext` folder or use `sencha framework upgrade ext` with the path where the framework is downloaded. Another option is to create a new empty project and copy your code there.

Comment: Probably you have met next problem
i try to use sencha framework upgrade ext v6.5.2\
I download ext-6.5.4 version and put it into my project but.., 
I'm getting an error stating that the framework was not found in the repository: 'Package 'v6.5.2' was not found in the repository.' Additionally, in the workspace.json file, the 'frameworks' field becomes empty. Initially, it looked like this:
"frameworks": {
"ext": {
"path": "ext-6.5.2",
"version": "6.5.2"
}
},
but now it looks like this:
"frameworks": {

},
and the framework itself is removed from the project.
@Peter Koltai

Comment: And what do you think, could it be connect with version of Sencha Cmd i use Sencha Cmd v6.5.3.6< and maybe i should use Sencha Cmd v6.5.2
@Peter Koltai

Comment: I think Sencha Cmd version does not matter, you can use older frameworks with a newer cmd. Do you have somewhere downloaded the framework you want to install?

Comment: No, I still couldn't find where to download the Ext JS framework version 6.5.2 specifically. However, the previous developer provided me with the framework itself, but it's unclear where they obtained it from.
I was also given the Ext JS framework version 6.5.3, and everything is working fine with it.
But in my case i should use ext 6.5.2
@Peter Koltai

Comment: There is not much different between the minor versions. Since I use Sencha as a paying customer I have no experience but I am pretty sure it is documented how to download. I use my Sencha Support account to download different versions. Maybe try to create a new project following the [Getting Started here](https://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.0/).